# flot how to show the x-axis values instead of y-axis when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am working on flot, when i hover on a point, i got a label contains the values on y-axis. is it possible to have the x-axis values instead of the y-axis counterparts ?

this is my options:

```
           chartOptions = {
               xaxis: {
                   min:0
               },
               yaxis: {
                   ticks : 0
               },
               series: {
                   lines: {
                       show: false,
                       fill: false,
                       lineWidth: 3
                   },
                   points: {
                       show: true,
                       radius: 4,
                       fill: true,
                       lineWidth: 3
                   }
               },
               grid: {
                   hoverable: true,
                   clickable: false,
                   borderWidth: 0
               },
               legend: {
                   show: true, 
               },
               tooltip: true,
               tooltipOpts: {
                   content: '%s: %y'
               },

               colors: App.chartColors
           };
```

Comment: Does changing `content` to `'%s: %x'` solve the problem?

Comment: @RickHitchcock yes it works, kindly write an answer please

Comment: Thanks, but I think the credit should go to @StephenThomas.

Comment: @RickHitchcock okay, do you know what `%s` means please?

Comment: %s is the series label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [`jquery.flot.tooltip`](https://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip) plugin, it's a simple option:

```
tooltip: {
    // ...
    content: "%x"
}
```

If you want to get fancy, you can provide a callback function and create whatever content you want for the tip.